# How to customize core admin pages within a theme?

Tags: customization, themes, templates, wp-admin

Say I'm building a WordPress theme, and when this theme is active I want to display customized versions of some admin pages. Let's suppose I want a custom "Widgets" page:

I can find the template for the page in '/wp-admin/widgets.php' but that's outside of my theme and is susceptible to being overwritten after an update.

My question is: Is there a reliable and safe way of displaying customized versions of core WordPress templates by theme, while keeping the original versions?

Comment: Really it depends on what you're trying to do. You can enqueue JS and CSS into the admin panel which will allow you to inject styles and some limited functionality, what is your end goal?

Comment: I would like to serve an independent custom template for that page, so that I can potentially use any WP API's related to the template.

Comment: To my knowledge there's no way to do this without recreating the page(s) and functionality entirely. That being said some of the pages have filters to add your own additional information ( such as fields onto Settings pages ).   You can [create your own pages](https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus) with your own functionality and append them to the admin menu.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought... it seems like there is no "official" way of customizing core admin pages. Maybe creating a route inside the theme to redirect you to your version, although I don't like that so much. I'll keep investigating, thank you!

Comment: Check out Calypso https://github.com/Automattic/wp-calypso and see how they went about it.

Comment: It was pretty big at WordCamp this year and shows which direction WordPress in going to move as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, you can't. The backend is not "theme-able" beyond enqueuing stylesheets and JavaScript. You can make significant changes that way, but the basic structure will stay the same.

All you could do would be remove the Core pages from the menus and replace them. To the extent that you could do that, and I am not sure how far along you could get, it would be a lot of code and would probably result in a resource intensive site.

Comment: Yes, I guess that's the way it's going to be for the forseeable future. Can't complain, given that it wasn't intended for the tool (wp) itself to be so customizeable, maybe future releases will start looking into this. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you will ever see this kind of customization. You would be altering/destroying Core functionality. I don't know how you'd make the backend customizable in a way that doesn't also make it not-WordPress.

Comment: Who knows. Obviously WordPress focuses on allowing customization of the front-end, not the back; but it could become much more powerful allowing anyone who knows what they're doing to customize the administration, as it is in the end one of the strong points for using WordPress in the first place. A simple "wp-admin" folder inside a theme would be great to overwrite admin templates.